# 1993 Mazda MVP gets hot only when pressing on accelerator

Tags: fuel-system, mazda

We have replaced hoses and water pump and have had no problem with it getting hot. In the past week it has started to get hot, not overheated. It only happens after driving on highway when pressing the accelerator. Once you stop pressing on the gas pedal, the temperature drops. When you at a complete stop the temp drops down to the midway point on the gauge but when you go again the temp roses again.

Comment: See also the following questions: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/4805/57, http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/5003/57 and http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/7972/57

Comment: Also check to ensure there isn't debris (like a plastic shopping bag) in front of the radiator (or AC condenser if applicable). This can cause weird cooling issues.

Comment: Another thought ... check to ensure your hoses going to/from the radiator aren't collapsing. When the system is hot, you step on the throttle, the water pump will increase it's movement of fluid, which can collapse a weak hose.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a faulty thermostat which is stuck partially open. Also check your coolant level on a cold engine. Use the marks on the expansion tank but do exceed the maximum mark.

Answer (score -1):

Your radiator, if original, is 11 years old and may be full of scale depending on 
water quality in your area. It may need replacing/rodding out/recoring. Also, check that the bottom hose you purchased has spring inside to prevent collapse. I always use quality premixed
coolant so water quality is not an issue. N.B. some people will tell you to discard
thermostat. BAD idea. Had the exact same problem with my V8 shorty 40 and above solutions
resolved problem. Sitting on 110kph with 38c. outside temp. temp. gauge hovers around 85c.